# find out which popup button was clicked

Tags: jquery-mobile, popup

given the example below

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupDialog" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="b" data-dismissible="false" style="max-width:400px;">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
<h1>Delete Page?</h1>
</div>
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <h3 class="ui-title">Are you sure you want to delete this page?</h3>
<p>This action cannot be undone.</p>
    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b" data-rel="back">Cancel</a>
    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow">Delete now</a>
    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow">delete it tomorrow</a>
    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow">delete it next week</a>
</div>
```

Then the following javascript code used to open the dialog

```
$("#popupDialog").popup("open");
```

Can somebody tell me how do I tell which button was clicked ?

Comment: giving each one a different class is the easiest option.

Comment: ok if I do that how do I tell which button was clicked after the modal has closed?

Comment: Attach listeners to the buttons e.g. `$(".cancel").on("click", doSomething)`, `$(".deleteNow").on("click", doSomethingElse)`, etc.

Comment: OK, got that now, thanks for your help